# File to HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a file on memory and I want to construct a HashMap of the type:

```
HashMap<Date, List<String>>
```

out of it. A sample record of the file is as follows:

```
[1987-11-19=[Ashwin Anthony, 100000065750184, /sdcard/DirPrime/1389422388122.jpg]
```

The sample code I have is:

```
public void readSDMap(){
         try{
                File toRead=new File("/sdcard/DirPrime/filetwo.txt");
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(toRead);

                Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);

                HashMap<Date,List<String>> mapInFile=new HashMap<Date,List<String>>();


                String currentLine;
                while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                    currentLine=sc.nextLine();

                    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(currentLine,"=",false);

                        **//error here**
                        The method put(Date, List<String>) in the type 
                        HashMap<Date,List<String>> is not applicable for the 
                        arguments (String, String)
                    mapInFile.put(st.nextToken(),st.nextToken());
                }
                fis.close();
                System.out.println(mapInFile);
                //print All data in MAP
                for(Map.Entry<Date,List<String>> m :mapInFile.entrySet()){
                 //   System.out.println(m.getKey()+" : "+m.getValue());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){} 
    }
```

How to reconstruct the map, I am not able to get the logic of making the value part of the map. Which is a list.

**EDIT**
(This is just a quick solution, please ignore the dirty manner in which I convert the string to date)
    After parsing the Date:

```
Date d = null; 
                try {
                    d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"/*, current*/).parse(st.nextToken());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Date    d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());






                mapInFile.put(d1,st.nextToken());
```

I am interested in resolving the later part oof the equation, of constructing a List.

Comment: the error message is pretty clear..
you are putting (String, String) but u have defined your map to store (Date, String)

Comment: Yes my question was not about the error message but about how to construct a list so that I can put it inside.

Comment: k my bad.. n so I commented and not answered your question :D

Comment: My Bad too, should have specified. Have edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put the data to the map as `String`s, not in the format you should (`Date` and `List <String>`). You'll have to convert the strings to the formats.

```
String dateStr = "1987-11-19";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
// *********
String listStr = "[A,B,some text]";
String cut = listStr.substring(1, listStr.length - 2);
String[] array = cut.split(",");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

The map key is a Date, you'll have to fix this line:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(st.nextToken());
mapInFile.put(date, Arrays.asList(st.nextToken().split(" ,")));
```

Note that you can use multiple delimiters when you split the right hand side string.

Comment: I will parse the date, however how do I construct the list, the later part of the map?

Comment: I tried that earlier but it will give: The method put(Date, List<String>) in the type HashMap<Date,List<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (Date, String[])

Comment: Why don't you just split the string according to the delimiter(s) in the file? The split will give you a String[] array.

Comment: Just use Arrays.asList() to convert.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns an unmodifiable list, so if you want a modifiable one use `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array))`.

Answer (score 1):

May be try something like:

```
currentLine = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");

StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(currentLine,"=",false);

.......

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
mapInFile.put(df.parse(st.nextToken()), Arrays.asList(st.nextToken().split(",")));
```

Comment: remove additional char like '['

Comment: This approach leaves the `[` and `]` to the List's values.

Comment: yep use substring to remove `[` and `]`
... or simply use `str .replace("[", "");` and `str .replace("]", "");`

Comment: ^ i know and so I'm using `Array.asList()`